# Como são gerados os ids no trello?

Tags: trello

Estou estudando um pouco a api do trello e tive a seguinte duvida:
Como é gerado o id dos cards, boards e lists do trello?
Será que é utilizado algum tipo de hash? 
Desde já muito obrigado!

Comment: Não são [GUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)?

Comment: É justamente isso que eu gostaria de saber, não tenho certeza de como são gerados...